# Is this the correct way to share and close a PDO connection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

We've experienced some issues with our website going down from what I believe is an overload of database connections when running bulk processes from old code. This code was not dealing with closing database connections at all.

Can you confirm that this is an efficient way of going about a shared database connection?

common.php (included at the top of every php file on the server):

```
// Set a global DB connection
$db = new dbConnection();
$global_conn = $db->pdoConnect();
```

class_example.php:

```
public static function myFunctionName($) {

        // Example query
        $sql = "SELECT * ";
        $stmt = $GLOBALS['global_conn']->prepare($sql);
```

I would then perform the following, nulling the shared global connection at the very end.

```
require_once "/includes/db.php";
require_once "/includes/class.php";

class->myFunctionName();

$global_conn = null;
```

Is one "null" of the connection variable enough. I don't need to do this in the functions that use it do I?

Comment: _Set a global DB connection..._ Why? Hands off from globals

Comment: If I have multiple functions all requiring a database connection, wouldn't a global connection be a good way to go about it, rather than creating a connection and closing it per function?

Comment: _wouldn't a global connection be a good way to go about it..._ IMO no! I'd rather stick to oop principles

Comment: [how to avoid opening multiple db connections using OOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176084/how-to-avoid-opening-multiple-connections-to-the-db-with-oop-php) - might help

Answer (score 1):

I don't particularly like global variables randomly popping from nowhere in the middle of arbitrary methods<sup>1</sup> but, performance wise, you're effectively using a single connection all across the script **as long as you aren't opening persistent connections** by setting the `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` flag (you don't really say). PDO doesn't have a class method to close connections so this is [as close as you can get](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php#example-1035):

> The connection remains active for the lifetime of that PDO object. To
>   close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring that
>   all remaining references to it are deleted—you do this by assigning
>   `NULL` to the variable that holds the object. If you don't do this
>   explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your
>   script ends.

The last statement means that you only need to do it explicitly if you want to release it early (i.e., you no longer need it but your script still has stuff to do).

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Database connections are not special variables. They can be used as function parameters or class properties like any other type and, since they're objects, what you're passing around is a reference to the same instance. E.g.:

```
public static function myFunctionName(dbConnection $global_conn) {
}
```